# How can I get selected value id in dropdown on vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a dropdown in a vue component and want to get selected option value

```
 <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" >
    <option v-for="user in users" v-model="kudouser" v-bind:value="user.id" >{{ user.id }}&nbsp;{{ user.first_name }}&nbsp;{{ user.last_name }}</option>
 </select>
```

I expect the output is When someone click option 1 need to get the option value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `v-model` in your option tag :

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="selected" >
                                     <option v-for="user in users"  v-bind:value="user.id" >{{ user.id }}&nbsp;{{ user.first_name }}&nbsp;{{ user.last_name }}</option>
                                 </select>
```

Comment: then how can i get the id

Comment: I got it We can use selected to get the ID .. Thanks